# Data Grid view only displaying one letter in the cell

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, datagridview

I am trying to add rows to a `datagridview` and when loading the from it only displays one letter on the variable I am trying to retrieve.

```
Dim col As New DataGridViewTextBoxColumn 'adding the colunm player to the data grid view
    col.HeaderText = "Player"
    DataGridView_displayfigures.Columns.Add(col)
    DataGridView_displayfigures.Rows.Add(New String({AssignRuns.batsman1A}))
```

This is the structure

```
Structure AssignRuns
    Shared batsman1A As String = PlayerSelection.player1_cmbox.Text
    Shared batsman1Aruns As Integer
```

I don't understand this. any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 2):

This is a perfect example of why you should have `Option Strict On`. You are use a `String` constructor here:

```
DataGridView_displayfigures.Rows.Add(New String({AssignRuns.batsman1A}))
```

But that is definitely not doing what you intend. You are passing a `String` array as an argument but there is no `String` constructor that has a parameter of type `String` array. With `Option Strict On`, that would generate a syntax error and your code would fail to compile until you fixed it.

With `Option Strict Off`, the compiler looks for a constructor that is similar enough that it can massage your code to work. In this case, it uses the one that has a parameter of type `Char` array. That constructor creates a `String` containing all the `Char` values from the array.

In your case, each `String` in your array is converted to a `Char` by simply taking the first character in each `String`. Your array only contains one `String` so only one `Char` is passed to the constructor, so the `String` that gets created only contains one character.

As well as that, there's no overload of that `Add` method that takes a single `String` either. There is one that takes an `Object` array though, so that's what you should be passing:

```
DataGridView_displayfigures.Rows.Add(New Object() {AssignRuns.batsman1A})
```

This would also work:

```
DataGridView_displayfigures.Rows.Add({AssignRuns.batsman1A})
```

That is technically passing a `String` array to the `Add` method but that is allowed because it's a widening conversion, i.e. no data can be lost. Converting a `String` to a `Char` is a narrowing conversion because data can be lost, as it was in your original code. `Option Strict On` allows implicit widening conversions but not implicit narrowing conversions.

EDIT:

Actually, thinking about that last code snippet and the fact that you can pass a `String` array directly to `Add` makes me think that maybe your mistake was just to misplace a single closing parenthesis because, rather than this:

```
DataGridView_displayfigures.Rows.Add(New String({AssignRuns.batsman1A}))
```

you could have had this:

```
DataGridView_displayfigures.Rows.Add(New String() {AssignRuns.batsman1A})
```

Moving that closing parenthesis means that you are denoting a `String` array and then initialising it, rather than passing a literal `String` array as an argument to a constructor.

Answer (score 0):

You can try me this way to add rows and columns in the DataGridView control.

```
Public Class Form1

    Structure AssignRuns
        Shared batsman1A As String = "player1"
        Shared batsman1Aruns As Integer = 3
    End Structure

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        'definite  columncount and then add columns of datagridview1
        DataGridView1.ColumnCount = AssignRuns.batsman1Aruns
        DataGridView1.Columns(0).HeaderText = "Player"

        'add rows of datagridview1
        Dim row As String() = {AssignRuns.batsman1A} 'You can try {AssignRuns.batsman1A,AssignRuns.batsman1A,AssignRuns.batsman1A}
        DataGridView1.Rows.Add(row)

    End Sub
End Class
```

[image]